# All git commands are hanging

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm working on a repository on a remote server. The repo uses LFS and totals ~10GB of files. I was able to check out this branch with minimal issues, and have before now had no issues switching branches (this server and the git server are in the same room with 10GE connections). I've modified some code, and I'm trying to save it on another branch.

```
git checkout -b my_new_branch
```

Is hanging. I understand it's a big repo, but it's hanging for quite a long time. I tried

```
git diff
```

To no avail. It also hangs effectively indefinitely. I've yet to leave it for more than a few minutes but I don't see it doing any i/o in iotop.

I've tried cleaning up swap files. There were none so that is not causing any hang issues.

Is this just an indexer of some sort running for a ridiculously long time in git? I'm not seeing any CPU or I/O usage, which is misleading.

Comment: Is it possible `git gc` is running in the background? (That's oftentimes the culprit for a UI to hang, though I think you'd see it from a command line if something you did kicked it off.)

Comment: It doesn't appear to be. The branch checkout finally completed, it just took a concerningly long time

Comment: I assume you cannot repeat the problem? Checking out a new branch without changing your local worktree should be fast.

Comment: That is the thing I was doing that was causing the delay - `git checkout -b [a new branch]` was hanging. I don't see why this would take so long unless it's git reindexing the entire working tree into a new branch?

Comment: *The repo uses LFS and totals ~10GB of files* - this is *probably* the cause. When using LFS (which isn't Git: it's an *add-on* that sort of engulfs Git), the files *aren't stored in Git*, they're stored elsewhere. Those files have to be retrieved. LFS will try to cache them sometimes, but will have to go back to the original LFS server now and then. This may need to download the bulk of the files. It won't matter if you have a superfast network connection if the *LFS server* has a slow one, so check into that.

Comment: @torek I have the LFS username cache timeout on, so it should have asked me for user credentials if it was going to LFS, and everything in that server room is on 10GE unless it's on direct fiber

Comment: OK, so probably not *quite* that - but still worth looking into. I strongly suspect you're hitting an LFS issue. If you are using Linux, consider running the operation under `strace` to observe which system calls are being made at the point where things just stop happening. (This is harder to see with Git-LFS since it's written in Go and thus has the very complicated Go scheduler involved, but it might point to something.)